# Jquery little correct the function select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

The function to select options for (Country --> Region --> City)

All work good when the user was registration, but after this, if user need correct and change his region or city (By country **selected**), its dosn't show the SELECT Options with Regions. To show, user need change to another country and back to him country for see the region select and cities in the end.

Here i show the EXAMPLE of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/Nazaret2005/bPUbb/ with USA country selected.

Here is Jquery (from the url example)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#Main').change(function () {
        var a1 = $("#Main").val();
        var a2 = $(".Subselect").val();
        console.log(a1);
        console.log(a2);
        $(".Subselect").hide();
        $(".lastSel").hide();
        $("#" + a1).show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax_city.php",
            data: {
                    "country": a1,
                    "region": a2
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $(".region").html(data);
                $(".Subselect").show();
            }
        });
    });

    $('.Subselect').change(function () {
        var a3 = $(this).val();
        console.log(a3);
        $(".lastSel").hide();
        $("#" + a3).show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax_city.php",
            data: {
                    "city": a3
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $(".region").html(data);
                $(".Subselect").show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And here little different code with php/mysql,jquery and css https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i5ku2ld65c774bo/JgAqFXTnbK (In russian)

**P.S.:** *I show the example of the code not here (because code not short)* And sorry for my english. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**

Try this code i updated the code [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/bPUbb/21/). Call change event dynamically.

```
 $('#Main').change();
```

Comment: I don't see any changes. Edit: lol you change the css. **But** `.Subselect {
     display: none;
}
.lastSel {
    display: none;
}` **and this** `.Subselect, .lastSel {
    display: none;
}` **same**!

Comment: Thanks. I will check with my php code when be home... I see it work on example :-)  And so simple LOL